# How does firefox sync password recovery work?

Tags: encryption, web-browser, key-management, firefox

According to Mozilla [Sync-new-security-model](http://blog.mozilla.org/services/2014/04/30/firefox-syncs-new-security-model/), Firefox servers are not able to `decrypt` your sync data without your password. So I figured that, the browser generates a key from your password, encrypts the data and sends it over the wire without the key.

But if I forget my password, I can still recover it, by having firefox **send a password reset** email. According to this page: [ive-lost-my-firefox-sync-account-information](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/ive-lost-my-firefox-sync-account-information), you can't recover your sync password without your email.

1. How does password reset work?
2. How is Firefox able to `decrypt` your data on their servers without your old key and send it back to your browser for syncing?
3. Does it stores the old key somewhere or is there some weird `crypto` magic going on?

Answer (score 4):

[The specification](https://github.com/mozilla/fxa-auth-server/wiki/onepw-protocol#handling-a-forgotten-password) says:

> Note that, since the forgotten-password client never learns `kB`, any class-B data will be lost.

NB: `kB` is the private key.

Here's how it works:

- You generate a new password
- A new private key "wrapped" with your new password
- Your old data is lost

The developers of the protocol assumed that if you lost your password, you would still have a device with the data synced. Therefore your device would re-sync the data from scratch.

If you loose your devices AND your password, you're doomed.